# c# Process.Start doesn't execute in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some code looking like this:

```
 public async Task Create(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
           
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = @"c:\bat\" + filename, UseShellExecute = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'm triggering the code through an api call and the command window opens and the batch file executes fine.

But when I do exactly the same on the production server (Windows Server 2019, IIS 10) the process never starts. The api call is successful but the bat file never executes.

- I've changed the permissions of the folder (even to everyone to test)
- I've tried to add Local
- I've allowed the World Wide Web Publishing service to interact with desktop
- I've changed and tried all the different app pool permissions

But I can't get it to work.

Grateful for help!

Comment: You need to inspect the `Process?` object returned from `Start` .

Comment: Your method does not have to be marked async (since it does not awaits anything). Another enhancement would be to rename your method (because "Create (fileName)" - if I am a developer using your assembly, I would expect this method to create a file and name it with the argument value)

Comment: Any log messages, or events in the event log?

Comment: Likely the IIS worker has no rights to start a process. You should supply the `UserName` and `Password` properties of the `ProcessStartInfo` object with a user that has sufficient rights.

Comment: @JHBonarius where and how do I do that?

Comment: @Pettanord You can start by actually using your debugger...

Comment: @Dai it seems you didn't read the question. Or are you running a debug build and a debugger on your production server?

Comment: "Or are you running a debug build and a debugger on your production server?" - yes: it's not an everyday ocurrence, but it's often the best overall way to quickly solve an issue in production without spending time theorizing -also, you don't need a debug build to use a debugger: you can disable CLR JIT optimizations systemwide which allows for usable step-through debugging in most cases - but the main reason is to catch things like first-chance exceptions or just to inspect the state of a running process - e.g. with a CPU and/or memory profiler.